# Netsuite - How to get all items - no search, paginated?

Tags: php, api, netsuite

Hi I am trying to get data from netsuite and it's frustrating. So hard and I can't find good documentation about usage.

I am using this package:
https://github.com/ryanwinchester/netsuite-php

I want to get all the products, all the orders, all of everything to integrate it with a custom e-commerce.

I could't get it. I don't want to search for a parameter. I want all of them? does anyone know how to do it?

What I got so far is:

```
 $service = new NetSuiteService($this->getConfig());

 $request = new GetRequest();
 $request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
 //$request->baseRef->internalId = "123"; this is to retrieve a single one. ? 
 $request->baseRef->type = "customer";
 $getResponse = $service->get($request);
 dd($getResponse);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is documented here https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSTWP/NSTWP.pdf

**get** operation on page 194 literally says

> The get operation is used to retrieve a record by providing the unique id that identifies that record.

and I thin that you are looking forward is **getAll** on page 195

getAll

> The getAll operation is used to retrieve a list of all records of the specified type.

Looking at https://github.com/ryanwinchester/netsuite-php/blob/master/src/NetSuiteService.php you will find out that **getAll** method is already available too.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Get all is not supported for customer record.